# How To Change The Floppy Image Of Qemu?

Tags: linux, images, emulation, floppy, qemu

I'm developing my own OS, but I'm having some problems with Qemu, because I need to change the floppy image from `grub.img` to `os.img` while the emulation is running, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can open qemu's console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> then type:

```
(qemu) change floppy0 os.img
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> to switch back to the VM's display.

If you start qemu from a terminal, an easier way of doing this is to run qemu with the `-monitor stdio` option, which will give the same qemu console in the terminal window.